# URL rewrite for multilanguage site with .htaccess (Apache)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, multilingual

I can't figure out how to cut extension (.php) in .htaccess in case I already have 1 virtual sub directory.

1) localhost/admin/index.php?lang=en -> localhost/admin/en/
2) localhost/admin/index.php?lang=ru -> localhost/admin/ru/

For case 1) and 2) I wrote already and it works.
Resolved with -> `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)(/)?$ index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]`
Please consider that (en & ru are virtual directories)

3) localhost/admin/index.php?lang=en/createprofiles.php -> localhost/admin/en/createprofiles.php
4) localhost/admin/index.php?lang=ru/createprofiles.php -> localhost/admin/ru/createprofiles.php
For case 3) and 4) I wrote also and it works.
`RewriteRule ^([en|ru]{2})/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]`

But I would like to cut .php extension.
The final link must be like : **localhost/admin/en/createprofiles/**

Can you please help me :). I have tried everything (about 8 hours), but nothing works

Thank you !

Comment: Where does that strange URL come from: `/admin/index.php?lang=en/createprofiles.php` ? Though this certainly is possible from a technical point of view it breaks with all standards and practices. That should be `/admin/createprofiles.php?lang=en` instead. Or maybe `/admin/index.php?lang=en&action=createprofiles`...

Comment: You mean, if the url is
`/admin/createprofiles.php?lang=en`
can I use the rewrite rule and display it as `/admin/en/createprofiles/` ?

Comment: Yes and no and yes: you can certainly implement a rule to internally rewrite `/admin/en/createprofiles` to `/admin/createprofiles.php?lang=en`, why not? And no: you can not implement a rule that somehow magically alters the references you hand out. But yes, you certainly implement a second rule to externally redirect `/admin/createprofiles.php?lang=en` to `/admin/en/createprofiles` if required.

Comment: Can you please write an example of the right .htaccess rules for 1) `/admin/index.php?lang=en -> /admin/en/`
2) `/admin/createprofiles.php?lang=en -> /admin/en/createprofiles/`
Please note that : en can be ru also (I mean language selector should be for (en|ru))

Comment: Sure, I an give you an example...

Answer (score 0):

This would be an example which implements both directions:

1. requests to the "pretty URLs" are internally rewritten to the actual scripts and
2. (possible) requests to the actual scripts are externally redirected to the "pretty URLs"

This obviously is just an example, your real world scenario is typically a bit more complex. But this example should point you into the right direction...

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)lang=(en|ru)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?admin/?$ /admin/%1 [QSA,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)lang=(en|ru)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?admin/index\.php$ /admin/%1 [QSA,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)lang=(en|ru)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?admin/createprofiles\.php$ /admin/%1/createprofiles [QSA,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?admin/(en|ru)/?$ /admin/index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,END]
RewriteRule ^/?admin/(en|ru)/createprofiles/?$ /admin/createprofiles.php?lang=$1 [QSA,END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection (instead of the `R=301`) and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you Arkascha ! I will try to do it based on your example and explanation.